# When I save a nested model changing only file field, save event didn't trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, carrierwave, nested-forms

I'm using rails 3.2.11, mongoid 3.0.18, carrierwave (0.7.1) and carrierwave-mongoid (0.3.0)

Two models: Product has many Components. Component has a file field. I use gem nested_form for adding many component forms on product page.

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title
  field :image

  embeds_many :components, cascade_callbacks: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :components, allow_destroy: true
end

class Component
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :title
  field :author
  field :file

  embedded_in :product

  mount_uploader :file, BaseFileUploader
end
```

Controller:

```
class ProductsController < BaseController

  def update
    resource = Product.find(params[:id])
    if resource.update_attributes(params[:product])      
      redirect_to collection_path
    else
      resource.components.build unless resource.components # there should be always one component
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

And when I change(! this field already has value) only a file field, there is no save query to db.

But When I add force save in controller like

```
class ProductsController < BaseController

  def update
    resource = Product.find(params[:id])
    if resource.update_attributes(params[:product])
      resource.components.each do |component|
       component.save!
      end      
      redirect_to collection_path
    else
      resource.components.build unless resource.components # there should be always one component
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

And it works! Do you know what the reason can be here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing this issue. If I update another field as well as the file on my embedded document, the upload gets triggered. If its just the file, nothing happens.